# Updating MySQL primary key

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I have a table `user_interactions` with 4 columns:

```
 user_1
 user_2
 type
 timestamp
```

The primary key is `(user_1,user_2,type)`
and I want to change to `(user_2,user_1,type)`

So what I did was :

```
drop primary key ...  
add primary key (user_2,user_1,type)...
```

and voila...

The problem is that database is live on a server.

So before I could update the primary key, many duplicates already crept in, and they are continuously creeping in.

What to do?

What I want to do now is to remove duplicates and keep the ones with the latest `timestamp` (which is a column in the table).

And then somehow update the primary key again.

Comment: I suddenly feel bad for every single DBA I cursed under my breath...

Comment: the next time add a unique key with the same columns as the primary key, then update the primary key

Comment: @Ignacio, it's live on a server, but that's a backup-backup server :-). I am not a DBA, but I won't try this thing on a REALLY live server :-)

Comment: @knittl, yes that's what I thought now, very late though :-)

Comment: I always thought a table could only have ONE primary_key. You have 3 ?!? Maybe what you want is one PK and indexes on the other 2 columns?

Comment: @pixeline: It's a compound primary key.

Answer (score 316, accepted):

Next time, use a single "alter table" statement to update the primary key.

```
alter table xx drop primary key, add primary key(k1, k2, k3);
```

To fix things:

```
create table fixit (user_2, user_1, type, timestamp, n, primary key( user_2, user_1, type) );
lock table fixit write, user_interactions u write, user_interactions write;

insert into fixit 
select user_2, user_1, type, max(timestamp), count(*) n from user_interactions u 
group by user_2, user_1, type
having n > 1;

delete u from user_interactions u, fixit 
where fixit.user_2 = u.user_2 
  and fixit.user_1 = u.user_1 
  and fixit.type = u.type 
  and fixit.timestamp != u.timestamp;

alter table user_interactions add primary key (user_2, user_1, type );

unlock tables;
```

The lock should stop further updates coming in while your are doing this.  How long this takes obviously depends on the size of your table.

The main problem is if you have some duplicates with the same timestamp.

Answer (score 21):

If the primary key happens to be an auto_increment value, you have to remove the auto increment, then drop the primary key then re-add the auto-increment

```
ALTER TABLE `xx`
MODIFY `auto_increment_field` INT, 
DROP PRIMARY KEY, 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (new_primary_key);
```

then add back the auto increment

```
ALTER TABLE `xx` ADD INDEX `auto_increment_field` (auto_increment_field),
MODIFY `auto_increment_field` int auto_increment;
```

then set auto increment back to previous value

```
ALTER TABLE `xx` AUTO_INCREMENT = 5;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `IGNORE` keyword too, example:

```
 update IGNORE table set primary_field = 'value'...............
```

Answer (score 0):

insert into student(id)
values(1)
on duplicate key update
id =0;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).