# How to drop primary key which has auto_increment in same column

Tags: mysql

I want to change the column name of a table.

That column name is (ID) and that is primary key and auto_increment column.

I found the query to change the column name is

```
Alter table mytable change ID, AppID INT(11);
```

But its throwing error, Because of the primary key.
So i am trying to drop the primary key, But not able to drop primary key also.

How can i drop the primary key which has auto_increment in the same column.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

the first line will remove autoincrement, second one will remove key

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY id INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

you probably want to add the key back later using

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

First drop the auto increment property and then drop the primary key.
Refer - [Remove Primary Key in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111291/remove-primary-key-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Aashrick, you won't be able to drop primary key ... 
But, you could try a work around, and do something like drop your current table, and create it again, with the changes you would like.

```
drop table mytable;
create table mytable ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to link to specific answers, but I wanted to point you to this topic which helped me out in a similar situation:

[Updating MySQL primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341576/updating-mysql-primary-key)
The answer by franzras (at the bottom on my end) was the one that helped me out.

He says one needs to remove the auto-increment first, then we can drop and re-add the primary key as normal.